# How to get the name of the application in android?

Tags: android

I want to get the name of my application. How can i get that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for the label name, the package name, or the apk name?  Why do you need this info?

Comment: I am luking for the app name coz I need it at the time of starting the application.

Comment: The actual apk file name is arbitrary and shouldn't affect anything.  Why is the package name insufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use PackageManager#getApplicationInfo()

For getting the Application Name for all packages installed in the device.
Assuming you have your current Context object ctx

```
Resources appR = ctx.getResources();
CharSequence txt = appR.getText(appR.getIdentifier("app_name",
"string", ctx.getPackageName()));
```

Comment: It's returning the package name not the application name.

Comment: PackageManager#getApplicationInfo() ?

Comment: This makes the assumption that you've defined a resource string "app_name" which will typically be the case, but would only be true because that's the default generated by Android Studio. The resource key of the application label can be whatever you want. You should use `PackageManager.loadApplicationLabel()`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [PackageItemInfo -> nonLocalizedLabel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo#nonLocalizedLabel) to get application name.

```
val applicationName = context.applicationInfo.nonLocalizedLabel.toString()
```

---

[Old Answer]

Usually, we do add the application name with app_name string resource, so you can write below code to access the app name

```
String applicationName = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
```

Reference :  [Resource Types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html#stringresources)

But note that, this resource name is not mandatory and can be changed to any other string name. In that case, the code will not work. See the first code snippet which uses [PackageItemInfo -> nonLocalizedLabel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo#nonLocalizedLabel) above for a better solution.

Comment: @Downvoters Why downvotes here? Why not post a comment about it? Are not you a man?

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `PackageManager` class to obtain `ApplicationInfo`:

```
final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai;
try {
    ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
} catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
    ai = null;
}
final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
```

EDIT: `CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));`

This would `return the application name as defined in <application> tag of its manifest`.

Comment: I tried this code but it's returning the package name not the application name.

Comment: what about for this line,     CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

Answer (score 1):

Context has function getString(int resId): [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int))

so you can use it easily like this.

```
context.getString(R.string.app_name);
```