# How to get the application name of the APK programmatically (not installed)

Tags: android

Based [How to get the name of the application in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802780/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-application-in-android).

I have this snippet. `andPath| is the location of the APK.

```
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(andPath, 0);
ApplicationInfo appinfo = info.applicationInfo;
String packageName = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(appinfo).toString();

PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai;
try {
     ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
} catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
     ai = null;
}

final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
```

`applicationName` returns me the package name.

```
CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
```

`c` returns me `null`.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have a problem here i post the full code to get the application name

**its returns ApplicationInfo**

```
public List<ApplicationInfo> getApplicationList(Context con){
        PackageManager p = con.getPackageManager(); 
        List<ApplicationInfo> info = p.getInstalledApplications(0);
        return info;
    }
```

**it returns ApplicationName**

```
public String applicationLabel(Context con,ApplicationInfo info){
        PackageManager p = con.getPackageManager();
        String label = p.getApplicationLabel(info).toString();
        return label;
    }
```

**on your onCreate function paste the below code**

```
List<ApplicationInfo> info = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();

        info = list.getApplicationList(this);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.content);
        layout.setOrientation(1);
        int size = info.size();
        Log.d("size",String.valueOf(size));
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            Log.d("Val of I",String.valueOf(i));
            String appname = list.applicationLabel(this,info.get(i)).toString();
            Log.d("AppName",appname);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(appname);
            layout.addView(tv);
        }

    }
```

Comment: list is a object of class which contains getApplicationList and applicationLabel functions

Comment: but this is getting the application name based on the installed app right? is it possible to get the application name based only on the APK which is not installed? thanks for the reply btw!

Comment: Application name which is not installed means you want to get list of apks present in sd card ?

Comment: uhm no, i can retrieve the apks but what im trying to get is the application name of that specific apk without installing, is this possible? thanks!

Comment: i think its not possible to get application info without installing by installing that apk you can get

Comment: @Bucks: Sorry again, but what is 'list'? There is a "}" not needed at the end.

Answer (score 9):

This is how you can get the application label from `not yet installed` APK file:

```
public static String getAppLabel(PackageManager pm, String pathToApk) {  
    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(pathToApk, 0);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
        // those two lines do the magic:
        packageInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir = pathToApk;
        packageInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir = pathToApk;
    }

    CharSequence label = pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
    return label != null ? label.toString() : null;
}
```

No need to patch the `applicationInfo` prior to SDK 8. See [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9151) for more details.

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted as the correct answer, since it perfectly suits the answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String applicationLabel (ApplicationInfo info){
     PackageManager p = con.getPackageManager();
     return p.getApplicationLabel(info).toString();
}
```

I hope you got application info pass that application info to this function it will give application name.

Comment: i tried this but it gives me the package name. my application info is based on the APK which is not installed

Comment: @Bucks: Sorry, but what is 'con'? Context?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit, con must be context.

Answer (score 0):

```
String title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use regular expression to get the name and compare with the app Label.

Comment: This was published as an answer, but possibly it should be a comment, otherwise please edit your answer and add an explanation that may be useful.