# Get current app package name using Appium AndroidDriver

Tags: android, webdriver, appium

There is method to get current activity in AndroidDriver:

```
driver.currentActivity()
```

which returns string like `.MainActivity` without package name. Is there any way to get full activity name or application package separately?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not yet possible.

Because Appium is using Selenium WebDriver, WD protocol should be extended / modified for that.

Answer (score 0):

This method `driver.currentActivity()` to get current activity based on the current page.

Use `.getCapabilities()` to get package name and activity name:

```
//return package name
driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("appPackage").toString();
//return activity name, as generic (not based on current page)
driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("appActivity").toString();
```

Reference : [Docs](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps#android-only)

Answer (score -1):

You can fire ADB Command from your code Like:
adb shell
cd data/app
ls

[Or do it programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362534/how-to-get-the-application-name-of-the-apk-programmatically-not-installed)

Comment: device is not directly connected when you use appium, so your solution will not work

Comment: What do you mean by "directly connected" .

Comment: That means i had device cloud available through selenium grid and appium